# wysiwyg text editor for Markdown. LocomotiveCMS

Tags: ruby, content-management-system, locomotivecms

LocomotiveCMS seems doesn't have a markdown editor.

Can anyone tell me if I can have a fully featured wysiwyg markdown editor? May be someone already has forked and implemented it. Or at least any help would be appreciated.